# node - diagnostics with repl.start() - access to all variables etc

Tags: node.js, express, debugging, read-eval-print-loop

I'm running a server with node.js (espress). I've defined a diagnostic/debugging function which I can add to any controller. The function mostly just prints out values of certain variables in the console.

Example:

```
function ConsoleDebug(req, res) {
    console.log(variable1)
    console.log(req.someObject.otherObject.variable2)
}
```

and is added to a controller like so:

```
router.get('/URL', function(req, res, next) {
ConsoleDebug(req, res);
res.render('someview');
});
```

I want to make the whole diagnostic/exploratory process more dynamic and I've read a whole deal of great things about the Node.js REPL and I figured I wanted to run it at any point in code.

I've added it to the ConsoleDebug() function, so it runs anytime the router is triggered using

```
function ConsoleDebug(req, res) {
    console.log(variable1)
    console.log(req.someObject.otherObject.variable2)
    repl.start({useGlobal: true})
}
```

It starts nicely, but it doesn't have access to any of the variables or scope at the point it is started. I would like to be able to write

> req.someObject.otherObject.variable2

and get the same output as is produced by

> console.log(req.someObject.otherObject.variable2)

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to use the REPL to dynamically tinker with any other node.js command at any point in code with respect to the scope where it was started, so that I don't have to keep rewriting the code in ConsoleDebug(), saving, restarting the server and observing the results.

Is that even doable or is there a more appropriate method/tool?